# What to do to get insights data from facebook pages that i don't own

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get access to the insights of other people's pages via my facebook app , And even with their access_token (with manage_page and read_insights) , i can't access their insights , and i verified the access tokens in the debugger and they mention that they're including manage_page and read_insights permissions . So i'm searching for a code or something that helps . 
Thanks .

Comment: What problem are you encountering when you use their access token with read_insights permission?

Comment: Are you using the user access token or the page access token?